# Is there spyware contained in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

Will there be any spyware be contained in the next LTS version 16.04?

I'm asking this because Ubuntu has been associated with spyware [in earlier versions](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/richard-stallman-calls-ubuntu-spyware-because-it-tracks-searches/).

Comment: Stallman claiming something does not make it true.

Comment: It is not a spyware. Online search will be disabled by default

Comment: I think this question is relevant because it asks about the latest version, whereas the other question discusses a previous version.

Comment: spyware! only search queries were given in the older versions!

Comment: I'm refering to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Amazon_controversy That's congruent to the definition of spyware (so it isn't just Stallmans opinion..) and it definitely hasn't been disabled by default in 14.04.

Comment: You could easily have found the information yourself. It been widely mentioned in sites covering Linux.

Comment: That's true for most questions covered here. But maybe it helps to point out such practices against the manifesto from time to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to search tracking, [no, there won't](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/ubuntu-online-search-feature-disabled-16-04). In 16.04/Unity 8, your search information will not be sent to Canonical unless you opt in. As an Ubuntu team member puts it, "What is changing? [First of all online search will be off by default.](http://www.whizzy.org/2015/12/online-searches-in-the-dash-to-be-off-by-default/?utm_source=omgubuntu)  This means that out-of-the-box none of your search terms will leave your computer."